# CAShapeLAyer not found?

Tags: ios

Im having a problem i cant seem to figure out, google searches and all. Im trying to access CAShapeLayer in my program and everytime i use this line of code CASHapeLayer *layer = [CAShapeLayer layer] i get this error message

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CAShapeLayer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in NCIStaticBg.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I cant seem to understand why its not working. For one core graphics is always added to every project you create by default. So adding #import to any file should allow me to use this class. When i type out CA... i am able to see CAShapeLayer in intellisense. Also whats really weird is that i can open up one of my older projects and those projects use CASHapeLayer, i get no errors at all. So its specific to this project, ive even created a new project and still the same error occurs. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 11):

Are you linking against QuartzCore.framework?  I bet you haven't added that framework to your new project.

Comment: Wow just wow i cant believe i forgot all about that..... Many Points to you dude many many points